# Linear programming problem - do we have enough data here?

Tags: linear-programming

I am to solve a following problem, but it seems to me that it is ill-formulated, i.e. there's not enough data. Am I right? If not what would be the mathematical model for it?

> Every coffee table produced gives company 9\$ revenue. Every bookshelf - 12\$. The company is small and has limited resources. For every production cycle (about 1 week) it uses 10 gallons of lacquer and 12 lengths of high-quality wood. Every table requires 1 gallon of lacquer and 2 lengths of wood. Make a linear programming model of the production plan decision problem and solve how many tables and shelves should be produced a week, and how big the revenue can be.

It seems to me it cannot be solved since we do not know how many resources does the production of shelves take, do we?

Comment: Yes: you need to know what is the technology to produce bookshelves.

Comment: I think you are right. The answer in this case: Produce so many bookshelfs as you can or the market requires.